# Java MessageFormat - replace value at an index

Tags: java, messageformat

I'm having a String like this :

```
{0}/suhdp run -command "suhilb" -input /sufiles/{1} -output /seismicdata/mr_files/{2}/ -cwproot {3}
```

The values at the 0th and the 3rd index need to replaced first. Later on, the 1st and 2nd indexes will replaced (on the already partially formatted String) and finally used.

I played around a bit with [ChoiceFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/ChoiceFormat.html) but was not able to pipe it with the [MessageFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) class to achieve what I want to.

Any pointers are welcome !

Comment: Is this going to cope with files with spaces in the name?

Comment: I slightly changed your question to try and make it easier to understand (which will get you more answers). Please make sure everything's still as you intended

Comment: Since your arguments to `MessageFormat` are delayed, you could consider using a builder

Comment: See my answer, it may give you some hints on how to do it

Comment: @artbristol 
Yes, the file may have a space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't fill all values at once, I'd suggest you use a builder:

```
public class MessageBuilder
{
    private final String fmt;
    private final Object[] args;

    public MessageBuilder(final String fmt, final int nrArgs)
    {
        this.fmt = fmt;
        args = new Object[nrArgs];
    }

    public MessageBuilder addArgument(final Object arg, final int index)
    {
        if (index < 0 || index >= args.length)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("illegal index " + index);
        args[index] = arg;
        return this;
    }

    public String build()
    {
        return MessageFormat.format(fmt, args);
    }
}
```

This way you can do:

```
final MessageBuilder msgBuilder = new MessageBuilder("{0}/suhdp run -command \"suhilb\" -input /sufiles/{1} -output /seismicdata/mr_files/{2}/ -cwproot {3}", 4)
    .addArgument(arg0, 0).addArgument(arg3, 3);

// later on:
msgBuilder.addArgument(arg1, 1).addArgument(arg2, 2);
// print result
System.out.println(msgBuilder.build());
```

This code probably lacks some error checking etc, and it is far from being optimal, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks ! It served my purpose !!!
Just for the sake of making the code generic, how can the no. of indexes to be replaced in a String(in my case, 4) can be found so that the MessageBuilder can be used by strings with different no. of indexes to be replaced?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know, I don't really use `MessageFormat`. Your best bet is probably to try and experiment what happens if you enter the wrong number of arguments... As to find placeholders, I guess a simple regex can help you do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure the particular string `{somethinig}` is not being used in your string (as it seems to be the case) why not just keep the string as is and use [`String.replace`](http://javarevisited.blogspot.de/2011/12/java-string-replace-example-tutorial.html) to change it to whatever values you have later?

Answer (score 0):

Can this help?

Placeholders that should be replaced on second stage are quoted initially.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String partialResult = MessageFormat.format("{0} '{0}' '{1}' {1}", "zero", "three");
    System.out.println(partialResult);
    final String finalResult = MessageFormat.format(partialResult, "one", "two");
    System.out.println(finalResult);
}
```

Then your format string becomes:

```
{0}/suhdp run -command "suhilb" -input /sufiles/'{0}' -output /seismicdata/mr_files/'{1}'/ -cwproot {1}
```